# Group by and count based on muliple conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame with 4 columns. I want to produce a new data frame which groups by the first three columns, and provides a count of the instances of "Yes" in the fourth column

So

[image]

becomes

[image]

How do I do this in R

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi nir020. Please do not post images of code or data (as specified in this forums guidelines). If you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) you could make it easier for others to find and test an answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you!

Comment: what do you mean @dario, it is inperfect .NORM format.. pleze update your system to read ;-)  https://xkcd.com/2116/

Comment: @Wimpel you desearve +10 points for sharing this link! LOL

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if I had a set of your actual data to verify this works and returns the output you desire, but the following should work.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(across(1:4)) %>%
  summarize(Count = sum(`Passed Test` == "Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `base R`

```
aggregate(`Passed Test` ~ ., df, FUN = function(x) sum(x == "Y"))
```